# Why are remove() and removeChild() not working

Tags: javascript, dom

Well I don't exactly understand if its the functions or the flow of my program. I'm querying a simple API for practice which fetches the longitude and latitude of ISS.I wanted to do it every second that's why I used `setInterval()`. Now I want that when the next data comes the current one automatically removes/disappear and the only the displays, that's why I tried using remove() and removeChild() both but its not removing the element and the new data keeps appearing one below the other. Here's the javascript:

```
const url = "https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544";
const box = document.getElementById('div');

function setup(){
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = gotData;
    request.open('GET',url);
    request.send();
}
setInterval(setup,1000);
function gotData(){
  data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  const box_lat = document.createElement('H2');
  const box_long = document.createElement('H2');
  box_lat.innerText = "Latitude:  " + data.latitude;
  box_long.innerText = "Longitude:  " + data.longitude;

  document.body.appendChild(box);
  if(box.hasChildNodes()){
    box.removeChild(box_lat);
    box.removeChild(box_long);
  }else{
    box.appendChild(box_lat);
    box.appendChild(box_long);
  }
}
```

This gives the following error:---

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at XMLHttpRequest.gotData (http://127.0.0.1:3000/Projects/CSS_JS/JavaScript/iss.js:30:9)
```

I also tried using `box.childNodes.length > 0` in the `if` condition but still got the same result.

Using `document.body.removeChild(box)` to remove the complete box item never shows that div element!

All I want is that data should update automatically without repeating!

Comment: In `box.removeChild(box_lat)`, `box_lat` refers to the element you just created (`const box_lat = document.createElement('H2');`). That element hasn't been appended as child yet. If you want to refer to `box`' current children, you can iterate over `box.children`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> box.removeChild(box_lat);
> ```

You are trying to remove `box_lat` from `box`.

> ```
> const box_lat = document.createElement('H2');
> ```

but you just created `box_lat` a few lines before and haven't appended it anywhere.

---

It sounds like you are trying to access the `box_lat` variable from the **previous** invoke of the function … but that's a different variable with a different value and you don't have access to it here.

---

You need to find the elements you actually want to remove, e.g.:

```
box.querySelector("h2").remove()
```